# How to setup OkHttp to request gzipped resources and NOT un-gzip them

Tags: okhttp

I'm looking at `new OkHttpClient.Builder()` to see whether there's a setting that would allow me to do 'raw' GETs of resources and then get the compressed bytes for that resource in the response. As far as I can see OkHttp transparently ungzips payloads. I can't see a way of initializing OkHttpClient to not do that. I've tried googling for "gzip OkHttpClient.Builder" and I get a bunch of unrelated inexact matches. I'm missing something obvious. Obviously :-(

Comment: The right kind of interceptor might help, or maybe you need to remove a default interceptor...

Answer (score 1):

Set this request header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Or replace `gzip` with `identity` for no compression. In either case OkHttp won't interfere if you provide your own `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  Presumably all of these are possible with those header settings: 1) OkHttp gets it gzipped, and hands it to me (end-user) unzipped, 2) as #1 but hands it to me still gzipped, 3) gets it uncompressed and hands it to me like that.

Comment: You got it. If you specify the accept-encoding yourself OkHttp won’t interfere.